# Select next input type field Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="form-row itemrow">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="item">Item <span style="color:#ef172c;"> *</span></label>
        <input name="item" type="text" data-parsley-trigger="blur" required  class="form-control item" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="price">Price <span style="color:#ef172c;"> *</span></label>
        <input  name="price" type="number" data-parsley-trigger="blur" required  class="form-control price" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="qty">Qty <span style="color:#ef172c;"> *</span></label>
        <input  value="1" name="qty" type="number" data-parsley-trigger="blur" required  class="form-control qty" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="totalforone">Total</label>
        <input name="totalforone" value="100" type="number" data-parsley-trigger="blur"  class="form-control totalforone" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button id="addmore" style="height: 34px; margin-top: 2em;" class="btn btn-sm btn-success add-more btn-block" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Item</button>
    </div>
</div>

function calculation(){
    var price = $(".price").val();  
    var qty = $(".qty").val();  
    var aa = $(this).next().find('div > .totalforone').val();
    console.log(aa);
};

$(".price").bind('keyup mouseup', calculation);
$(".qty").bind('keyup mouseup', calculation);
```

I have these rows for multiply price and quantity eah row enter price and qty manually and total in input type total.
**Want to set price x qty = total each row. i have an option to add more rows[image]**

Comment: I am not able to understand your question, what is the result you want? can you explain a bit more

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass `this` to the function so that you can refer that inside the function. Then you can target the closest row with *.itemrow* to find the relevant *.totalforone* to set the calculated value. Also, it is better to use `input` event instead of `keyup` and `mouseup`:

```js
function calculation(el){
  var price = $(".price").val();  
  var qty = $(".qty").val();  
  $(el).closest('.itemrow').find('.totalforone').val(price * qty);
};

$('body').on('input', '.price', function(){calculation(this)});
$('body').on('input','.qty', function(){calculation(this)});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row itemrow">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="item">Item <span style="color:#ef172c;"> *</span></label>
    <input name="item" type="text" data-parsley-trigger="blur" required  class="form-control item" />
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="price">Price <span style="color:#ef172c;"> *</span></label>
    <input  name="price" type="number" data-parsley-trigger="blur" required  class="form-control price" />
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="qty">Qty <span style="color:#ef172c;"> *</span></label>
    <input  value="1" name="qty" type="number" data-parsley-trigger="blur" required  class="form-control qty" />
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
<label for="totalforone">Total</label>
<input name="totalforone" value="100" type="number" data-parsley-trigger="blur"  class="form-control totalforone" />
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
<button id="addmore" style="height: 34px; margin-top: 2em;" class="btn btn-sm btn-success add-more btn-block" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Item</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its perfectly work but when i clicked on Add Item it duplicate all input Item, Price, Qty and Total. So, in duplicated row function not working. Can you help me more please.
 I used function for duplicate in document page ready.
`$(".add-more").click(function(){ 
 var html = $(".copy").html();
 $(".newRowHere").before(html);
var countrow = $("form .itemrow").length;
console.log("TOTAL ROWS -- > " + countrow); });`

Comment: @AbdullahBhatti, in that case you have to use delegation approach, I have updated the answer, please check:)

Comment: `function calculation(el){
var price = $(el).closest('.itemrow').find(".price").val();
var qty = $(el).closest('.itemrow').find(".qty").val(); 
  $(el).closest('.itemrow').find('.totalforone').val(price * qty);
};
$('body').on('input', '.price', function(){calculation(this)});
$('body').on('input','.qty', function(){calculation(this)}); `

Thanks Mamun Solved !
Just Some Changes in your given function. Your answer very helpful Thank you so much.